# Conversion Failed Varchar to Date with TOP and WHERE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've got a MSSQL 2012 server that holds olders databases (day by day) of my ERP. Simple JOB restores a newest databases from my backup server and removes the oldest one's. It was working fine for few months, but a week ago it started to fail. One of the queries returns: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

All database have the same schema for a name 'DATABASE_date' ex.: 'DATABASE_20150224'.

This is the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 name 
from sys.databases 
where name like 'DataBaseName_%' 
order by CAST(right(name,8) as DATE)
```

IF i remove 'TOP 1' it works fine.

```
SELECT name 
from sys.databases 
where name like 'DataBaseName_%' 
order by CAST(right(name,8) as DATE)
```

It seems like MSSQL check's all databases on this server (2 new databases of a different app). But why? There's a 'WHERE' cluase and simple select works just fine.

Comment: And you repeated this several times ?

Comment: Why do you need to cast those 8 characters as a date anyway? Assuming you have yyyymmdd it will sort the same direction as a string as it will as a date.

Comment: Btw underscore is a special character using like. Name like 'DataBaseName_%' is same as Name like 'DataBaseName_%'. What you meant is name like 'DataBaseName[_]%'

Comment: Yes - i'm reapiting this severeal time in cursor. Job restores all databases that he will find in specific folder. Sometime we have problems with network and cmd scrips can't copy a database. Next day he copies 2 database at once. Then job resotore 2 new DB a delete 2 oldest ones.

About underscore - You're right, just missed that when creating question. That was only example of a database name (real database name is different - without underscore) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is a declarative language.  A database is free to first order the rows and then filter them, or the other way around.

You are relaying on a `where` clause to filter out rows that would cause an exception in your string manipulation expression.  But SQL Server can run the `where` after the `order by`.

One approach is bullet-proofing the `order by`:

```
order by 
        case
        when name not like 'DataBaseName_%' then name
        else CAST(right(name,8) as DATE)
        end
```

Note that even this isn't 100% guaranteed to work.  SQL Server could legally evaluate both sides of the `case` and throw away the second one.

Comment: I was sure that `where` is before `order by` ... but obviously i was wrong and i was affraid that someone will tell me that :) It's the only logical explanation.

I've changed the script of the job - i'm creating temp table that holds the databases names (only that i want) with id column (identity(1,1)). Now i'm using something like that:

`
DECLARE @databaselist TABLE (id INT identity(1,1), dbname VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @databaselist
... 

SELECT name FROM @databaselist WHERE id = @id_db`